# Java run-time invoked by applet does not observe all JRE configurations when browser is launched at the service level

Tags: java, tls1.2

We have a kiosk that runs processes from a service that acts as a monitor.  That service runs as the system user.  When java.exe tries to load a JAR file from a server that allows TLSv1.2 only, the download fails.  We believe this is because when java.exe runs in this way, it doesn't see all the configurations (at least partially because the system user doesn't have an HKCU profile entry).

Is that correct?  Is there a way to overcome it?  We've tried -Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.2 in all conceivable environments, we've tried invoking the Java control panel from all the environments (including the system user), and we've run out of ideas.  It seems to be ignoring the Java console settings as well--so we can't look at a log to see what's happening.

We're at wit's end with it and not sure what to try next.  Any ideas on how to overcome this or at least diagnose it further?

Comment: Applets are dead. Time to rewrite your kiosk application.

Comment: “Fails” sounds like you have a stacktrace.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's not my application, and right now in this particular environment, it's one of the only choices.  Not my decision.  As for the stacktrace, nope, nothing. Not seeing a thing.

Comment: It's not my application either. As for making your applet work, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable to a pass a global java properties to all running JRE.

In your case, try to set `_JPI_VM_OPTIONS` as a system variable to make it global.

For an applet, try this

```
_JPI_VM_OPTIONS = -Dhttps.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html

Comment: Super--we'll ask that the team try that.  We'd already done JAVA_OPTS to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer involves installation policies, which our team thought was a pretty obscure thing to go wrong.  They're looking at changing the platform installer now